# Convert Python List into Dataframe with Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large python list consisting of many strings in the format

```
list = ['state1', 'town1','town2','town3', 'state2', 'town4', 'state3', 'town5','town6']
```

There are a variable number of towns for each state.

How can I get this to be nested so it looks like:

```
list = [['state1', 'town1','town2','town3'], ['state2', 'town4'],['state3', 'town5','town6']
```

And then from there make this list into a dataframe with the states as the indexes and the towns as a single column?

Comment: Hi Sam44, please submit a line or two of input as sample data and an example of the output that you are expecting.  Others may also encourage you to provide the code you tried to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's first look at some list examples:

```
state_lst = ['California', 'New Mexico', 'Arizona', 'etc.']
state_town_lst = ['California', 'San Francisco', 'Los Angeles', 'San Diego', 'New Mexico', 'Albuquerque', 'Santa Fe', 'Arizona', 'Tucson']
town_lst =[]
```

So as you can see there should be three cities for California, two for New Mexico and one for Arizona. So we go through the `state_town_lst`  and check if it the items appear in the `state_lst`.

```
for item in state_town_lst:
    if item in state_lst:
        state = item
        continue
    else:
        town = item
        
    town_item = (state, town)
    town_lst.append(town_item)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(town_lst, columns = ["State", "Town"])
```

This gives you:

```
    State       Town
0   California  San Francisco
1   California  Los Angeles
2   California  San Diego
3   New Mexico  Albuquerque
4   New Mexico  Santa Fe
5   Arizona     Tucson
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated my question to make it more clear. Since my list is not yet nested, how would I go about getting it to the nested format?

Comment: Are there any discernible ways of telling which entry in the list are states and which are towns? If not, you could make a list with every state name so this could be checked against. You could then split the list before every time a state name appears using a while loop

Comment: Yes, I have a list with all the state names. How would you go about splitting the list?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the list as:

```
lst = [['state', 'town','town','town'], ['state', 'town'],['state', 'town','town']]
```

To convert it into dataframe with state as index:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(lst).set_index(0, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
0        1       2       3
            
state   town    town    town
state   town    None    None
state   town    town    None
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated my question to make it more clear. Since my list is not yet nested, how would I go about getting it to the nested format?